# Application or Business/Domain layer's responsibility when choosing roles for new users

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, encapsulation

I'm having difficulty understanding which layer (application vs domain) should be responsible for adding roles to new users. Eg if an admin is created it should receive the admin role. I can see 2 approaches

Application layer responsibility:

```
public class AddBasicUserCommand
{
    public User Handle(string userName, string role)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Role = role
        };
        //... persist user to storage
    }
}
```

Domain layer responsibility:

```
  public class AddBasicUserCommand
{
    public User Handle(string userName)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Role = "basicrole"
        };
        //... persist user to storage
    }
}
```

The problem I see with pushing it up to the application layer is that when there are multiple clients/applications that can create users, they all have to agree on how to describe different roles, eg admin role is described by "admin". Eg, this can happen:

```
public class UserController
{
    public IActionResult CreateBasicUser(string userName)
    {
        //this happens at application 1
        var user = new AddBasicUserCommand().Handle(userName, "basicrole");

        //this happens at application 2
        var user = new AddBasicUserCommand().Handle(userName, "badrole");
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

When both of these clients/applications work on the same database users can easily be created with wrong roles.

Also each of the clients would need to tested for passing the correct role when creating each type of user.
If we move this responsibility out of the client the client becomes more fault tolerant:

```
public class UserController
{
    public IActionResult CreateBasicUser(string userName)
    {
        //this happens at application 1
        var user = new AddBasicUserCommand().Handle(userName);

        //this happens at application 2 - no chance of passing bad role value
        var user = new AddBasicUserCommand().Handle(userName);
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

My question is should this concern be handled on the domain side or is this part of authorization logic and should be handled on the client/application side?

Comment: I think this kind of question is best suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow

Comment: How exactly is that "opinion-based" ? There are plenty of pragmatic answers to make based on real criteria and constraints. It might be "too broad", but "opinion-based" ? ...

Comment: In my humble opinion, "opinion-based" is highly opinion-based. And most often yours, mine, and the community's opinion disagree. I am always wondering why this is a close reason at all. If opinions are based on and presented with facts, then that's very valuable. But that's for meta to discuss and others to decide. Until then we can play the "I don't think so, reopen" game at nauseam :-/

Answer (score 1):

> this concern be handled on the domain side or is this part of
>   authorization logic and should be handled on the client/application
>   side?

I would agree if you would said: is security a domain or an infrastructure concern?

In my humble opinion, both approaches can still provide a good separation of concerns.

Before continuing with my reasons, I would say that you should definitively implement this as domain code, because it's not only more *DDD-ish* but it increases reusability and consistency across all consumers of the whole domain: there's a single way of adding roles to your users.

Anyway, I would suggest you a mixed but yet powerful approach.

First of all, implement your security layer as *domain* as you would do regularly. Provide a security service to work with the whole security domain easily.

Secondly, in your infrastructure code, design some kind of façade interface like this:

```
public interface ISecurityFacade
{
     void SetUserRole(string userName, string roleName);
}
```

...and implement it to use your security domain.

The main advantage of this approach is others domain can collaborate with your security domain, while even non-domain code can work with your security layer.

You can even take this to the next level using dependency injection and inversion of control, and when you need to use your security layer outside any domain, you can inject `ISecurityFacade`, while if some domain requires to work with security, you may need inject `ISecurityService`.

Maybe you got lost on the difference of `ISecurityService` and `ISecurityFacade`.

`ISecurityService` can start or collaborate in a transaction, while the `ISecurityFacade` implement atomic methods: each one represents a full transaction.

The whole point of a façade is its consumers won't know if its implementation is using domain or who knows what: they blindly rely on the façade. In your particular case, you'll provide an implementation that will use the domain. For example: `DomainSecurityFacade`.

### About the use of command pattern...

This is just my opinion but it feels ugly if you want to leverage DDD. Your application layer should use either service or façades... you don't need commands.

For example, wouldn't be this more readable and understandable?

```
// Before
var user = new AddBasicUserCommand().Handle(userName, "basicrole");

// After
var user = SecurityFacade.SetRoleToUser(userName, "basicRole");
```

BTW, this is just my opinion...

### OP asked in some comment...

> If I understand this correctly you would create a facade but leave the
>   responsibility of choosing correct role for new users to the
>   application? Doesn't this still leave too much responsiblity to the
>   user of the domain/business layer?

No, the responsibility of setting the role to the user domain object is of the security domain.

Obviously, at some point, the application layer might use a domain service through an application service and it'll try to set a role to some given user.

You might argue that it seems like the responsibility of setting a role is of member of the application layer, but this layer won't work with the domain directly, it's just the *trigger* which starts a domain transaction.

At some point, maybe in your *user repository*, you should implement some kind of domain validation. I would use the *specification pattern*, and some `UserRoleAssignmentSpec` should validate that the role set to the user to be updated exists in order to avoid a data corruption.

Since who actually modifies the domain *is the domain itself*, and the domain can also validate itself to preserve it as is intended to work, who's ultimately responsible of handling security? ;)

Comment: If I understand this correctly you would create a facade but leave the responsibility of choosing correct role for new users to the application? Doesn't this still leave too much responsiblity to the user of the domain/business layer?

Comment: @neo112 You'll need to double-check my answer. I've already said that the code that implements *setting a role* should be in the domain layer.

Comment: @neo112 At the end of the day, some code will need to add the role. The responsibility of the domain is validating that the role exists, can be assigned, ... And the security domain itself should be able to authorize the operation.

Comment: @neo112 Check my latest update where I've explained your concern, I hope it clarifies it.

Comment: I have read your update. Do I understand it correctly that the application layer should depend on the Security Domain and invoke a method from that domain , eg SecuryDomainFacade.CreateAdmin("johnny", "admin"). It is then the job of the security context to validate that when creating an Admin the role must be either "admin", "superadmin" or whichever roles are valid for admin users. When the application layer tries to calls CreateAdmin("johnny", "notadmin") the Security Domain should should throw an exception or otherwise not proceed with creating an admin with wrong role?

Comment: @neo112 Excepting that you shouldn't use the façade implementation directly but the interface `ISecurityFacade`, and you shouldn't throw exceptions because the domain validation may be unsuccessful. You need to taylor some way to return domain results with success or unsuccessful, and you can return details of the failure.

Comment: Ok, but why use a wider interface in the application layer? Wouldn't it be better if the Security Domain/Security Facade offers an interface without the possibility to create users with wrong roles attached and instead attached correct roles itself depending on whether CreateAdmin or CreateNormalUser was called?  There would be less validation and testing overall.

Comment: @neo112 Now you need to take your time to organize your mind. If that validation would be implemented at the façade level, the domain could be corrupted if other façade or the application layer would also try to add users and roles...

Comment: @neo112 BTW, you know that C# has enumerations and this is the most powerful way to define a limited number of values. You don't need a string or many mehtods. Just one accepting an enumeration like `enum UserRole { Admin, SuperAdmin, Regular }`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is treat `Authorization` as a subdomain and give it its own Bounded Context. Clients will all go through this BC to add and get user roles.

You can choose to implement the `Authorization` BC with the DDD tactical patterns - if you do so, it will have its own Application, Domain and Infrastructure layers. 
Since role management is usually not that complex of a domain logic, you could also go for something more lightweight than DDD, like CRUD frameworks with quick application scaffolding, or transaction scripts. Part or all of the Bounded Context can consist of off-the-shelf authorization/access control solutions as well.

What can be more tricky is how to leverage Authorization in other Bounded Contexts to control access to your domains. If you want to stay simple, typically you will do that at the Application level, checking that the user has a sufficient role before performing the operation. How the Application Service/Command Handler obtains the roles of a user can take multiple forms with various levels of convenience and indirection, from using some kind of security context provided by the underlying technology to "manually" calling the Authorization BC. Behind the scenes, the Authorization BC will have to be contacted in some way, for instance directly calling the Authorization module if we're in-process, or sending a message to a REST service if out-of-process.